# Battery drain and over heating on Dell XPS L502X

Tags: power-management

I own a Dell XPS L502X and it works fine if is booted under "Windows 7". No issue(over-heat or quick-battery-drain) is observed while using the laptop.

After the recent installation of Ubuntu 14.04(Dual boot with Windows), the laptop gets heated up and battery drains up quickly if it is booted under Ubuntu.

Many websites suggest different work-around but am not sure about the exact one to follow. Please provide your suggestions on resolving this issue. Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2450M CPU@2.50GHz